Forest of growing weights in a graph
Given an undirected weighted graph $G = (V,E,\omega)$, we consider the relation $p[]$ defined by: for any vertex $v$, $p[v]$ is the vertex $u$ such that $\omega(v,u) = \max_{w\in N(v)} \omega(v,w)$ (we assume this vertex is unique).
In other words, each vertex "chooses" its neighbor linked to it with the largest weight.
This relation only has trivial cycles, namely $v = p[p[v]]$ when the maximal edge of $v$ it the same as the one of $p[v]$. One may see such an edge as the root of a tree, in which, for any vertex $x$, $p[x]$ is the parent of $x$. Therefore, the $p[]$ relation defines a spanning forest of the given graph.
I am sure this object appears in many contexts, has a name, and has been studied to some extent, but I found nothing. I would be highly interested in references, or keywords to search for.

I don't know about names, but this forest is used in one of the methods for finding maximum spanning trees in fast parallel time. Basically the forest is contracted to a set of super-vertices then the process is repeated.
